# How do I run multiple python scripts in sequence, with waiting one script to finish its job before another starts in every step?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have 10 web crawlers, and a preprocessing script(say, WS and PS each.)
What I want to do is the following:

1)There is a main script that controls everything, which is called 'Mother.py'

2)The 'Mother.py' runs 2 main tasks; [running 10 web crawlers at the same time] / [parsing the crawled data]

The problem is that I want my script to **wait** until the 10 web crawlers complete their jobs, and then execute the parsing script and so on.

So the pseudo structure will be like:

```
def Mother():
    run Crawler()
    #wait untile Crawler is finished.
    run Parser()
```

I googled for several methods such as 'subprocess' or 'threading',
but I found it difficult to understand and implement on my coding.

can this problem be solved by either 'subprocess' or any other simpler way?

Comment: Do you mean something like running: proc = subprocess.Popen(...) and then proc.wait()?

Comment: probably. I tried 
p1 = subprocess.Popen(somescript_1~~)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(somescript_2~~)

[p.wait() for p in p1, p2]

but this subprocess 'concept' is confusing..
have no idea what to do ..